# How Find the $f(x)$ such $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}}{f(x)}=1$

Tags: limits

find the value $f(x)$ such

> $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}}{f(x)}=1$$

This problem is china (2009College students' mathematical contest
  comption)  I have consider sometimes, and we know  we can't find this sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}$$
Thank you someone have nice methods

Comment: I really enjoy your questions here, math110 :)

Comment: Thank you very much @AntonioVargas

Comment: If I interpret this [paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/Asym_PAMS_final.pdf) correctly,  $\displaystyle\;\;\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n^2}\;\;$ 
has following asymptotic expansion as $x \to 1^{-}$:
$$\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} + \frac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}}}{2}
\left[\frac{\sinh\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}}
+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{(2^{2n+1}-1)B_{2n+2}(\sqrt{t})^{2n+1}}{2^{2n}(2n+2)!}H_{2n+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t}}{2}\right)
\right] + O(t^{N+1/2})
$$
where $t = -\log x$, $B_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Bernoulli number and $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Hermite polynomial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the [integral comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) we have

$$
\int_0^\infty x^{t^2}\,dt \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} \leq 1 + \int_0^\infty x^{t^2}\,dt.
$$

Now

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{t^2}\,dt &= \int_0^\infty \exp\left[-\left(t\sqrt{-\log x}\right)^2\right]\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log x}} \int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-\log x}},
\end{align}
$$

so

$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} 2 \sqrt{\frac{-\log x}{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} = 1.
$$

To simplify this a little we could use the fact that

$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\log x}{x-1} = 1
$$

to get

$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} 2 \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} = 1.
$$

Comment: Numerical calculations do not confirm that: $$evalf(Sum(.999^{n^2}, n = 0 .. infinity)) $$ produces $28.51794780 $, but $$evalf(sqrt(Pi)/(-2*ln(.999))) $$ gives $ 885.7837378$. If we put $x=0.9999$, then $$evalf(Sum(.9999^{n^2}, n = 0 .. 2*10^5)) $$ gives $ 89.12047691$ and $$evalf(sqrt(Pi)/(-2*ln(.9999))) $$ outputs $ 8861.826138$.

Comment: @user64494 if you have a question about the argument, feel free to ask.

Comment: @user64494, numerical calculations would confirm my answer if you had entered the right expressions into your calculator.

Comment: Numerical calculations confirm that: $$evalf(sqrt(Pi)/(2*sqrt(-ln(.999)))) $$ outputs $28.01794780 $.

Comment: Nice,This http://sms.math.ecnu.edu.cn/contest/university01/nonmathclass09_answer.pdf

Comment: @math110 ah, it looks like I found the same answer they did.

Comment: Pari/GP with 400 digits float precision gives $\small \begin{matrix} x & \sum (...) & 2 \sqrt{(...)}\cdot \sum (...) \\
 0.95000000 & 4.4130432 & 1.1134693 \\ 
 0.97500000 & 6.0697011 & 1.0829100 \\ 
 0.98750000 & 8.4017929 & 1.0599418 \\ 
 0.99375000 & 11.692435 & 1.0430377 \\ 
 0.99687500 & 16.340912 & 1.0307572 \\ 
 0.99843750 & 22.911203 & 1.0219107 \\ 
 0.99921875 & 32.200424 & 1.0155742 \\ 
 0.99960938 & 45.335550 & 1.0110531 \\ 
 0.99980469 & 63.910140 & 1.0078360 \\ 
 0.999902&90.1776& 1.00555
 \end{matrix}$ by *Mat(vectorv(10,r,[x=1-0.1/2^r, s=sumalt(k=0,x^k^2),s*2*sqrt((1-x)/Pi)]))*

Answer (score 0):

Maple does not compute the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sqrt{\frac{-\log x}{\pi}} (\vartheta_3(0,x)+1)
$$
but does show numerically the value $1.0000000000$ for it.

**added**

"Code" was requested.  Is that allowed in a math group?

[image: CODE MAPLE 17]

Comment: Could you kindly base your words by a code?