# How find this sum $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n^2}}{n}$

Tags: summation

**First, Merry Christmas everyone!**

Find this sum
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n^2}}{n},1>x\ge 0 \tag{1}$$

This problem is creat by Laurentiu Modan.and I can't see this solution.

I know this sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n}=-\ln{(1-x)},-1\le x<1$$

and I know this 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^2}\approx \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{1-x}},x\to 1^{-}$$

But for $(1)$,I can't find it,Thank you.

This problem is from this
[image]

Comment: I know But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n^2-1}$,I can't find it

Comment: Is this an exercise?

Comment: @Norbert,A journal of mathematics problems(2010)

Comment: So it is an open problem?

Comment: Obviously $|x|<1$, otherwise the sum diverges.

Comment: @Norbert,yes,I think this is open problem

Comment: This question was asked here within the last month (or two) ... or maybe in MO.  But I do not know how to search for $x^{n^2}$ in questions, so I cannot find it easily.

Comment: @GEdgar Is it possible your mistaking it with this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500303/how-find-the-fx-such-lim-x-to-1-frac-sum-n-0-inftyxn2fx/500330#500330.

Comment: @John: No that is not it.  There was an $n$ in the denominator, and a comment that theta functions may help.  But there may have been a factor $(-1)^n$, which is unimportant.

Comment: @GEdgar Perhaps, it got deleted.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a solution, but by playing around with the problem I found the following nasty looking identity:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n^2}}{n} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi\log(1/x)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{y^2}{\log(1/x)}}\log(2|\sin(y)|)dy$$

for all $0<x<1$. Note that the function we integrate over is singular at $y=\pm n\pi$ for $n\in Z$, but the integral itself is well defined. However, this integral seems even harder to evaluate as the sum. The derivation is quite simple: $f(x)$ can be though of as a solution to the heat equation $u(t,z)$ at $z=0$ and time $t=\log(1/x)/\pi$ with the initial condition $u(0,z) = -\log(2|\sin(\pi z)|)$.