# The infinite series of $x^{n^2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I have some troubles with the following series $$\sum^\infty _{n=0} x^
{n^2}$$

I'm suppose to show that this series is equivalent when $x$ approaches $1$ and $x <1$ to $$\frac{G}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ where G = $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$

I tried to use the series expansion of exponential function and then interchange the series and the integral but it doesn't work for obvious reasons .

Have you some tips ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However at my level we don't use such function ... It may be a trick to do it ...

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500303/42969.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

If $\ p:=1-x,\ $ then $\ x^{n^2} = (1-p)^{n^2} \approx e^{-n^2p}\ $ and
$\ S:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} \approx \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2p} $ but also
$\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2p} \approx \frac1{\sqrt{p}}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} dt
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{\sqrt{1-x}}. $ A bit more work gives us that
$\ S \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{\sqrt{1-x}}\ $ as $\ x\to 1^-.$

For example, if $\ x = 1 - 10^{-10},\ $ then the integral is $
\approx 88623.1925$ while  $\ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{\sqrt{1-x}} \approx 88622.6925. $

Comment: Nice work ! Thank you.